# How to set button image on Uiimageview on click method of button?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton

i want to set image of UIButton background image in UIImageview.image on click method of UIButton.

```
-(void)Click_save:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = sender;
    UIView *view  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, 320, 600)];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    UIImageView *imgview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 300, 600)];
    [view addSubview:imgview];

    imgview.image = btn.imageView.image;
 }
```

Comment: UIButton * btn = sender;
    UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, 320, 600)];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    UIImageView * imgview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 300, 600)];
    [view addSubview:imgview];
        imgview.backgroundColor = btn.imageView.image;

Comment: self.btn.setBackgroundImage(imgview.image, forState: .Selected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `image` property of your imageView not the `backgroundColor` property. Also you need to use [imageForState:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/imageForState:) property of your button to get the image.

Use:

```
 imgview.image = [btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: thanks @Midhun MP : i tried this way, image is not setting in UIImageview

Comment: @bhumi: is that image set as button image or as background image ?